# После старта openvpn клиента пропадает доступ через интернет

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Ubuntu18, openvpn из стандартного репозитория. Подключаюсь к рабочей сети с помощью комманды

```bsh
openvpn --config my_config.ovpn
```

И успешно - локальные хосты на той стороне доступны, могу подключиться к нем через ssh, например. Но вот беда: сразу после старта клиента не могу никуда зайти через браузер - все страницы оказываются недоступны. До этого ни разу не пользовался openvpn - подскажите хотя бы с чего начать поиск проблемы? Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте настроить подключение через графический интерфейс, скорее всего у вас появится возможность через настройки подключиться по VPN с указанием протокола OpenVPN. и там есть галочка, она называется примерно как "Использовать это соединение только для ресурсов этой сети", отмечаете эту галку для вашего VPN-соединения и проблема скорее всего будет решена.

Comment: также в конфиге можно попробовать добавить строку
"route-method exe" (без кавычек)
по моему это тоже решает проблему

Comment: насколько я понимаю эти настройки касаются сервера, а не клента, я прав?

Comment: в данном случае как настроен сервер не имеет особого значения, так как у вас уже клиент пытается добавить в роутинг данные с сервера, а там видимо запрещено трафик через него гонять (по умолчанию вроде так и работает) и эта галочка дает понять клиенту, чтобы он роутинг добавлял не для всего подряд, а только для IP из сети VPN.. примерно так.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Ubuntu 20.04, OpenVPN, использую настройки через GUI, хотя разницы по проблеме не заметил, запускать через консоль или интерфейс.

Можно предположить, что на это влияют настройки сервера VPN, к которому идет подключение. Он отправляет конфигурацию для автоматической настройки вашей сети (маршруты, DNS, шлюзы) и отсюда появляются проблемы.

Я нашел 4 варианта исправления проблемы, я воспользовался сначала третьим, затем вторым:

1. Обратиться к админам VPN и сообщить о проблеме. Если это их работа, то они должны помочь. Конфигурация той сети не должна влиять на вашу (**ее решаете не вы, а администратор сети, к которой подключаетесь**).
2. В настройках VPN в GUI (если через GUI идет подключение) указать "Использовать это подключение только для ресурсов в этой сети" («Use only for resources on this connection»). Нужные маршруты заработают, и интернет будет работать. **НО!** Если вы используете не IP-адреса, а именованные адреса серверов, например, *myhost.host.local*, то они скорее всего не будут работать. Вместо этого, для подключения нужно использовать IP-адреса этих хостов. Чтобы получить IP-адреса, можно использовать команду `traceroute <myhost.host.local - имя хоста>`, который выведет конечный IP-адрес хоста, если он доступен. Чтобы получить его адрес, у вас должна быть отключена галочка "Использовать это подключение только для ресурсов этой сети". Получив список IP-адресов вы можете указать их в файле `/etc/hosts` в соответствии с адресом или же везде, где вы используете именованные адреса, заменить их на IP-адреса. Эффект будет такой же, но во втором случае не требуются права root. Вы также можете спросить у администраторов уже готовый список этих именованных хостов и адресов.
   [image: Использовать это подключение только для этой сети]
3. Эффекта, который был достигнут в пункте 2, можно достигнуть путем указания конкретных маршрутов для конкретных IP-адресов. Для этого можно воспользоваться той же командой `traceroute <hostname>`, а также `route -n`. В результате этих команд вы получите список нужных вам адресов, как в решении 2 и укажите их в маршрутах для настройки сети. Можно также попробовать указать целую подсеть, если для вашей сети это актуально.
4. Можно в ваш файл конфигурации VPN указать опцию `pull-filter ignore "dhcp-option DNS"`. В этом случае вы столкнетесь с такими же проблемами как и в пункте 2 и решить их нужно будет также.

[image: Настройка конкретных маршрутов]

Answer (score 0):

1. Если вы пользуетесь Network Manager, то зайдите
   в настройки Вашего VPN подключения и
   установите чекбокс “Использовать это
   подключение только для ресурсов в этой сети”.
2. Введите команду в терминал

> sudo nmcli connection modify id VPN_NAME ipv4.dns-search '~.' ipv6.dns-search '~.' ipv4.dns-priority -50 ipv6.dns-priority -50

где VPN_NAME - имя подключения в network Manager